# Select is not updating when ng-model is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code like this:

```
  <select ng-model="mode" ng-init="mode=10">
    <optgroup label="Serif">
      <option value="0">Normal</option>
      <option value="1">Bold</option>
      <option value="2">Italic</option>
      <option value="3">Bold Italic</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Sans">
      <option value="4">Normal</option>
      <option value="5">Bold</option>
      <option value="6">Italic</option>
      <option value="7">Bold Italic</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Script">
      <option value="8">Normal</option>
      <option value="9">Bold</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Fraktur">
      <option value="10">Normal</option>
      <option value="11">Bold</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Monospace">
      <option value="12">Normal</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Double-struck">
      <option value="13">Bold</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <label for="text">Input Text</label>
  <input id="text" ng-model="input"/>
  <div>
    Output: {{input|convert:mode}}
  </div>
```

the mode scope value is changed, convert filter is executed with mode == 10 but the select is not update it still unselected. How can I fix select to be updated when scope variable change?

Here is [code pen](http://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/ENQWZg) that demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since option values are treated as `string` you need to set `ng-init` value as a `string` as below

```
<select ng-model="mode" ng-init="mode='10'">
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/eo091u00Z5uurJtijqnH?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry i dint see your answer, and you were 50 secs fast

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are binding a string value in ng-init it should be treated as string embeded with single quote, `mode='10'`

```
 <select ng-model="mode" ng-init="mode='10'">
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/GNQWzz)**